# Differentiating a Quadratic Form

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives

I'm having some trouble differentiating a quadratic form. I'm tasked with showing that $P(x) = \frac{1}{2} \left(b-Ax\right)^T C (b-Ax)$ is minimized by a vector $x$ satisfying $A^T C A x = A^T C b$. So far so good. I have trouble however completing the proof, and I feel like I'm missing something in the way I differentiate and deal with matrix transposes. Side note: We assume $C$ is symmetric.

Here's my attempt so far:
$$\begin{align*}
P(x) &= \frac{1}{2} \left(b-Ax\right)^T C (b-Ax) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} C (b-Ax ) (b-A x)^T\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left( (Cb-CAx) (b-Ax)^T \right) 
\end{align*}$$
Now, I will differentiate and set the derivative to 0:
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial P}{\partial x} = 0 &= \frac{1}{2}\left( \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} (Cb-CAx) \right) (b-Ax)^T + (Cb-CAx) \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} (Cb-Ax)^T \right) \right)\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left( A^T C^T(b-Ax)^T + (Cb-CAx) A^T \right)\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left(A^T C^Tb - A^T C^TAx + CbA^T - CAxA^T \right)\\
&=A^T C^Tb - A^T C^TAx + CbA^T - CAxA^T \\
A^T CAx + CAxA^T&=A^T Cb  + CbA^T
\end{align*}$$

At this point I get stuck.I Mean, assuming that $Ax=b$, I can reduce the last line to the desired expression, but I don't think I can assume that. I think I'm missing something obvious, but can't figure out what that something is. How do I need to continue?

Comment: In your first step, the right side changes from a scalar to a matrix, so something is wrong there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me double check your computation of $\nabla P$; to simplify notation even further, let $\langle x,y\rangle := x^T y$ be the usual Euclidean inner product. Since I'm not handy with matrix calculus, let me naively use first principles, i.e., $\nabla P(x)$ is the unique vector such that
$$
 \forall h \in \mathbb{R}^n, \quad P(x+h) = P(x) + \langle \nabla P(x),h \rangle + O(\|h\|^2).
$$
Now,
$$
 P(x+h) = \frac{1}{2}\langle b-A(x+h), C(b-A(x+h))\rangle\\
=\frac{1}{2}\langle b-Ax,C(b-Ax)\rangle + \frac{1}{2}\langle -Ah,C(b-Ax)\rangle + \frac{1}{2}\langle b-Ax,-CAh\rangle + \frac{1}{2}\langle Ax,Ax\rangle\\
=P(x) + \frac{1}{2}\langle C(b-Ax),-Ah\rangle + \frac{1}{2}\langle b-Ax,-CAh\rangle + \frac{1}{2}\|Ah\|^2\\
= P(x) + \frac{1}{2}\langle-A^TC(b-Ax),h\rangle + \frac{1}{2}\langle-A^TC^T(b-Ax),h\rangle + \frac{1}{2}\|Ah\|^2\\
= P(x) + \langle-A^TC(b-Ax),h\rangle + O(\|h\|^2),
$$
so that
$$
 \nabla P(x) = -A^TC(b-Ax).
$$
What happens now when you set $\nabla P(x) = 0$?